# In Evolution, how do I attach my public key to a message?

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, gnupg, enigmail

If I'm writing a message in Thunderbird, I can attach my public key by simply selecting Enigmail | Attach my public key. (Rather than using the regular file attachment button to attach my public key file as I would any other file.)

How do I do this in Evolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evolution does not have a feature for quickly attaching the public key like this. Instead, attaching a public-key is like attaching normal file.

You'll need to locate the public-key in your folder, and attach it to the mail.

[Adding Attachments in Evolution](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-attachments-sending.html.en)

**Attaching files**

To attach a file to your email in the composer:

> 1. Click Add Attachment…, or click Insert ▸ Attachment, or press Ctrl+M.
> 2. Select the file you want to attach.
> 3. Click OK.

- You can also drag a file to the attachment bar of the composer window.

When you send the message, a copy of the attached file goes with it.